# Reactive forms - how to call separate action on one field only within form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following simple form.  I want a button that checks to see if the username is available with one specific field.  If username is available, then main submit button is enabled.  How do I achieve this? Is this a form within a form?

```
<form mat-dialog-content [formGroup]="myForm"> 
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput formControlName="firstName" />
  <mat-error>{{ error }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput  formControlName="lastName" />
  <mat-error>{{ error }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput formControlName="username" />
  <mat-error>{{ error }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

//This button needs to be disabled unless username is filled out.  If user changes username the main submit button should be disabled unless user checks with this button.
<button (click)="userNameCheck()" >Check if available</button>


<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput formControlName="notes" />
  <mat-error>{{ error }}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<button (click)="save()" [disabled]="myForm.invalid">Submit</button>
</form>

export const FORM_CONTROLS = {
  firstName: [null, Validators.required],
  lastName: [null, Validators.required],
  username: [null, Validators.required],
  notes: [null],
}


this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group(FORM_CONTROLS);

save() {
    const myData  = this.myForm.value;
    this.myService.saveData(myData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is bad practice to have a form within a form. **"form must not contain other form elements.** [HTML Prohibitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions)

The best approach would be to declare a property eg `usernameCheckField` and include it in your form binding to `ngModel` see below example

```
<input type="password" [(ngModel)] = "usernameCheckField" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" />
```

note the `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`. This will enable you to use template driven for model inside a reactive forms model.

A better approach to checking if a user exists would be to subscribe to the `valueChanges` property of the `username` field in your `ngOnInit` life cycle hook

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm.get("username").valueChanges.pipe(
    mergeMap((username) => this.myService.checkIfUserExists(username)),
    tap(res => {
      // Do some operations here
    })
  ).subscribe()
}
```

**Do not forget to unsubscribe from the subscription!**. Your may consider using `takeWhile` or `takeUntil` operators from `rxjs/operators` for this

Comment: Is this the recommened approach?  Seems like it's getting away form using reactive forms?

Comment: @Owen, remember that valueChanges happens when you change the input, this suppose severals calls to the service

Comment: @KingKongFrog, the "recomended aproach" is use async validators:https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#creating-asynchronous-validators. Another aproach is that the button was enabled always and before submit, check if emailExist.

Comment: @KingKongFrog @Eliseo I provided the second approach to ensure you maintain a reactive form approach. For the several calls problem, consider piping the `debounce` operator and setting an interval between which a user types and the time a call is made to the service, and instead of `mergeMap` use `switchMap` that cancels earlier observable when a new stream is provided, in this case when user types